# How to not return a regex match if a user agent string contains Chrome?

Tags: regex, user-agent

I have want to create a regex pattern that will provide a match for a safari user agent string. The problem is that Chrome also seems to match:

Safari Regex:

```
(?!Chrome).*Safari
```

This still matches against a Chrome user agent string, but I thought that the negative look ahead would resolve this issue?

Chrome user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
```

Safari user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27
```

Can anyone provide me with a regex solution for this?

**Update:**

The answer I was directed to at [Efficient User-Agent Regex to find Safari in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885173/efficient-user-agent-regex-to-find-safari-in-python) does not provide a regex solution for this problem. In fact, it doesn't address the issue at all, so I am suprised it was accepted as an answer

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient User-Agent Regex to find Safari in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885173/efficient-user-agent-regex-to-find-safari-in-python)

Comment: Use `^(?!.*Chrome).*Safari` or, to ensure whole words are checked for, `^(?!.*\bChrome\b).*\bSafari\b`

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^(?!.*Chrome).*Safari
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GwGajH/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!.*Chrome)` - fails the match if there is `Chrome` substring after 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `Safari` - `Safari` substring.

**Update** (fixing issues in your answer)

## Regex for Safari:

```
^(?!.*(?:Chrome|Edge)).*Safari
```

## Regex for Chrome:

```
^(?!.*Edge).*Chrome
```

## Regex for Edge:

```
/Edge/
```

Comment: Excellent. And thank you for the explanation. Much appreciated. I will accept this as the answer...

Comment: @CharlesRobertson Great, please do.

Comment: Others answers are great, but this is the right one for the question.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
^(?!.*\bChrome).*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EhDwfN/2/)

Or,

```
 ^(?!.*\bChrome).*\bSafari
```

If you are looking for the Safari match without Chrome specifically

The issue with your regex `(?!Chrome).*Safari` is you need the `.*` to match what is in front of the `Chrome` in the negative look assertion at the start of the string.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for this, and to think the moderator was pointing me to a previous post with an accepted answer that was completely off topic. I knew there was a regex solution, out there...

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Wiktor Stribiżew & @dawg excellent answers, I felt it might be useful for anyone looking for a complete solution to the 3 browsers that contain 'safari' in their user agent string:

**Regex for Safari:**

```
^(?!.*Chrome|Edge).*Safari
```

**Regex for Chrome:**

```
^.*Chrome(?!.*Edge)
```

**Regex for Edge:**

```
Edge
```

Comment: I added fixes for the issues in this answer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this basic one? It matches Safari only.

`.*(Safari).*`

See test on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IjHqcY/1).

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are correct for desktop and maybe Android.
For iOS:

```
^(?!.*CriOS).*Safari
```